# Display images from remote server in web app using PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, web-applications, mobile

Im using PhoneGap to create a HTML5 news application app on Android, iOS and Blackberry.

This app pulls articles from a website which I've built in PHP. The article contains title and content as well as images.

I get the article title and content with JSON. What is the best way to get the images?

Should I just get the image path and display the reference to the remote image in the app? What are the problems with this method (I think Apple may not approve of such a method)? Or should I download the image and save it to the file system? Therefore I will have it even when offline...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should download it and save it to the file system, you can check the size on the remote server, if it changes then re-download. Using the size is also good to make sure the image has successfully downloaded. I think apple would be fine with this because you are not referencing a whole website as the app but instead just some external content.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you tell me the advantage of this over, say, referencing it? Im basing the design on the Pulse app. Im wondering how that app displays images so quickly..